# Scrapy skips image downloads

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

I am trying to scrape image URL's from multiple pages. This is working fine and it outputs all the URL's in my command prompt. However there are only 40-70 images downloaded when I run the spider, this amount of images that should be scraped are 4000.

```js
import scrapy
from stscrape.items import ImageItem
import logging
import json
from PIL import Image

class StSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "lst"

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
             'https://www.example.com/api/?subcategory=lts&page=1'
        ]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        logging.warning('in page')
        jsonresponse = json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())
        pages = jsonresponse['data']['pagination']['total_pages']
        for page in range(pages):
            yield scrapy.Request(url='https://www.example.com/api/?subcategory=lts&page=' + str(page), callback=self.page)

    def page(self, response):
        pageresponse = json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())
        items = pageresponse['data']['segments'][0]['segment_items']
        image_url = []
        for item in items:
            image_url.append(item['product_card']['image_url'])
        yield ImageItem(image_urls=image_url)
```

I think the problem has to do with the process of the image downloads. I feel like it somehow blocks more images from being downloaded.

**EDIT**

This is what scrapy outputs

```
2018-01-23 21:43:20 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 91540,
 'downloader/request_count': 160,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 160,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 1313499,
 'downloader/response_count': 160,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 160,
 'dupefilter/filtered': 1,
 'file_count': 55,
 'file_status_count/downloaded': 55,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 23, 20, 43, 20, 693000),
 'item_scraped_count': 99,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 316,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'request_depth_max': 1,
 'response_received_count': 160,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 100,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 100,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 100,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 100,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 23, 20, 43, 5, 45000)}
2018-01-23 21:43:20 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

I think the problem is that once 1 URL has been processed and the images have been placed in the image_urls, they will be processed with Yield. This somehow blocks other images from being processed.

Comment: What does the log say? Can you share it?

Comment: The log works. I shall edit my post to clarify

Comment: I don't doubt the log *works* :-) But it may contain valuable information for us, so it would be best if we could see it.

Comment: @TomášLinhart I'm sorry, i thought you meant the logging.warning()

Comment: I see you get some pages filtered as duplicate. Might that be the reason? Also, how do you know there should be 4000 images scraped? Did you actually count it?

Comment: Yeah there is 40 per page and there are 100 pages. I did set filter duplicate to false.

Comment: Did it solve the problem?